# Code specific for specific products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

So I have this code that changes the variable price according to what the option the customer selected.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'check_if_variable_first' );
function check_if_variable_first(){
    if ( is_product() ) {
        global $post;
        $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
        if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            // removing the price of variable products
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );

// Change location of
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_wc_template_single_price', 10 );
function custom_wc_template_single_price(){
    global $product;

// Variable product only
if($product->is_type('variable')):
    // Main Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
    $price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( '<span class="from-price">From:</span> %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    // Sale Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
    sort( $prices );
    $saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( '<span class="from-price">From:</span> %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    if ( $price !== $saleprice && $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        $price = '<del>' . $saleprice . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</del> <ins>' . $price . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</ins>';
    }

    ?>
    <style>
        div.woocommerce-variation-price,
        div.woocommerce-variation-availability,
        div.hidden-variable-price {
            height: 0px !important;
            overflow:hidden;
            position:relative;
            line-height: 0px !important;
            font-size: 0% !important;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('select').blur( function(){
            if( '' != jQuery('input.variation_id').val() ){
                jQuery('p.price').html(jQuery('div.woocommerce-variation-price > span.price').html());
                jQuery("p.price").prepend('<span class="stack-price">Your Stack: </span>');
                console.log(jQuery('input.variation_id').val());
            } else {
                jQuery('p.price').html(jQuery('div.hidden-variable-price').html());
                if(jQuery('p.availability'))
                    jQuery('p.availability').remove();
                console.log('NULL');
            }
        });


    });
    </script>
    <?php

    echo '<p class="price">'.$price.'</p>
    <div class="hidden-variable-price" >'.$price.'</div>';

endif;
}

        }
    }
}
```

The code was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912300/replace-the-variable-price-range-by-the-chosen-variation-price-in-woocommerce-3

However I only want that code to apply to two specific products.
I tried adding  `$product_ids = array( 375, 39 );`  after `if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {` but it didn't work.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
if(is_product() && get_the_id() == 1253) {
// your code here
}
```

get product id first

Comment: thanks but that works for one product (one product ID).. But I have two products I need to apply that code to.

Comment: It's pretty simple to adjust the "if" to check for either of 2 products. Do a bit of research on conditionals and "or" statements.

Comment: use it like if(is_product() && (get_the_id() == 1253) || get_the_id() == 1254))  {